# SQL Query for getting date

Tags: mysql

SQL Query Writing regard to date.

I tried this `query.Datatype` of `OrderDate`  is `datetime`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '01/07/1996' AND '31/07/1996';
```

I'm getting this message

> `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: change to date format `Y-m-d`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL dates are in **Y-m-d** format. Your query should be (if the `OrderDate` column datatype is [Date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)).

```
Select * from Orders 
Where OrderDate Between '1996-07-01' AND '1996-07-31'
```